# VBA How to use events on worksheet change interlinked between two columns

Tags: excel, vba

Have a bit of a problem and need your help with updating my VBA code.

I have two columns, 1st column displaying % of the 2nd and the 2nd column being a number. Cells need to be recalculated based on user input, which is why I used an event on worksheet change (code below). What I managed to do is have the 2nd column modified whenever you change the % in the 1st.

Now I'd like to find out how I could (if possible given the case), modify it so that if the user changes the % in the 1st column it recalculates the 2nd (which I have) OR if the user changes the 2nd column it would recalculate the % in the 1st, all the while without retriggering itself over and over.

This is what I have. Any help appreciated.

Column 1 being "P" and Column 2 being "Q"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Dim WsCY As Worksheet, WsM As Worksheet
Dim CVal As String
Dim Found As Range

'Sheets I'm working with
Set WsCY = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current Year Data")
Set WsM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
'Value used to search for the base value on which the % from 1st column is applied
CVal = WsM.Range("C10")
Set Found = WsCY.Columns("B").Find(what:=CVal, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Target.Address = WsM.Range("P13").Address Then
    WsM.Range("Q13").Value = WsM.Range("P13").Value * WsCY.Range("AB" & Found.Row) + WsCY.Range("G" & Found.Row)
ElseIf Target.Address = WsM.Range("P15").Address Then
    WsM.Range("Q15").Value = WsM.Range("P15").Value * WsCY.Range("AC" & Found.Row) + WsCY.Range("H" & Found.Row)
ElseIf Target.Address = WsM.Range("P17").Address Then
    WsM.Range("Q17").Value = WsM.Range("P17").Value * WsCY.Range("AD" & Found.Row) + WsCY.Range("I" & Found.Row)
ElseIf Target.Address = WsM.Range("P21").Address Then
    WsM.Range("Q21").Value = WsM.Range("P21").Value * WsCY.Range("AE" & Found.Row) + WsCY.Range("J" & Found.Row)
ElseIf Target.Address = WsM.Range("P23").Address Then
    WsM.Range("Q23").Value = WsM.Range("P23").Value * WsCY.Range("AF" & Found.Row) + WsCY.Range("K" & Found.Row)
ElseIf Target.Address = WsM.Range("P25").Address Then
    WsM.Range("Q25").Value = WsM.Range("P25").Value * WsCY.Range("AG" & Found.Row) + WsCY.Range("L" & Found.Row)
Else
End If

End Sub
```

2nd example of what I'd need:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.Address = WsM.Range("P1").Address Then
    WsM.Range("Q1").Value = WsM.Range("P1").Value * 100
ElseIf Target.Address = WsM.Range("Q1").Address Then
    WsM.Range("P1").Value = WsM.Range("Q1").Value / 100 - 1
Else
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should turn off events at the beginning and end of your Change event procedure:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
...
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you meant by that. I made up a 2nd example and tried it out but doesn't do anything. How would I use the Application.EnableEvents to basically stop it once a change is made?